# how to Yii2 faker database relation

Tags: php, database, orm, yii2, faker

How to create fake record with **Yii2 Faker** for ORM table?
For example:

```
User:
 -id
 -email
 -password
 -auth_key
 -password_reset_token
 -name
 -family
 -user_img
 -is_admin

users_detail:
 -id
 -user_id
 -phone_number
 -country
 -city
 -facebook_url
 -googleplus_url
 -linkedin_url
 -instagram_url
 -comment
```

`app.tests.codeception.unit.templates.fixtures` files code:

Fixture file `User.php`

```
return [
    "email" => $faker->email,
    "password" => Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash('password_' . $index),
    "auth_key" => Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString(),
    "password_reset_token" => Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString(),
    "name" => $faker->firstName,
    "family" => $faker->lastName,
    "user_img" => $faker->image(Yii::getAlias("@app/web/uploads/users"), 200, 200, null, false),
    "is_admin" => $faker->randomElement(array("1", "0"))
]
```

relation fixture `user_details.php`

```
return [
    "user_id" => ??? I don't know ???,
    "phone_number" => $faker->phoneNumber,
    "country" => $faker->country,
    "city" => $faker->city,
    "facebook_url" => $faker->optional()->url,
    "googleplus_url" => $faker->optional()->url,
    "linkedin_url" => $faker->optional()->url,
    "instagram_url" => $faker->optional()->url,
    "comment" => $faker->optional()->realText()
];
```

I need to create data for user_details table with faker for some user in user table

Comment: Pick an amount of users to create from the user template and then let faker generate a random number between 1 and your chosen amount. So if you generate 50 users (with auto incremented id starting at 1) you can randomly insert a number between 1 and 50 in the other template.

Comment: Thanks @jagsler , it was useful for me

Comment: You can select random id from the user table: "user_id" => (new \yii\db\Query())->select(['id'])->from('user')->orderBy(new \yii\db\Expression('rand()'))->one()['id'],

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution that has worked for me is to control the id generation of the master records and use this value also in the referring field(s).

user.php faker definition:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $faker \Faker\Generator
 * @var $index integer
 */

$security = Yii::$app->getSecurity();

return [
    'id'            => $index + 1,
    'username'      => $faker->userName,
    'email'         => $faker->email,
    'auth_key'      => $security->generateRandomString(),
    'password_hash' => $security->generatePasswordHash( 'password_' . $index ),
    //'password_reset_token' => $security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time(),
    'confirmed_at'  => time(),
    //'last_login_at' => time(),
    'flags'         => 0,
    'created_at'    => time(),
    'updated_at'    => time(),
];
```

Associated token.php faker definition:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $faker \Faker\Generator
 * @var $index integer
 */

$security = Yii::$app->getSecurity();

return [
    'user_id' => $index + 1,
    'code' => $security->generateRandomString(),
    'created_at' => time(),
    'type' => 1,
];
```

The $index variable starts default with 0. MySQL does not like ID 0 values so +1 needs to be added.

This will generate the user.php fixture like:

```
<?php

return [
    'user0' => [
        'id' => 1,
        'username' => 'arjun.lindgren',
        'email' => 'lquitzon@mitchell.com',
        'auth_key' => 'yDL6BzlyxBOAFbK15uQ-Fx_AVEqZhE06',
        'password_hash' => '$2y$13$SRyNY1ZceQdVMjDFEYaNxeTs0yr5raTgRsquzh6Czom/0loAX9C3W',
        'confirmed_at' => 1506074296,
        'flags' => 0,
        'created_at' => 1506074296,
        'updated_at' => 1506074296,
    ],
    'user1' => [
        'id' => 2,
        'username' => 'jaqueline.bartoletti',
        'email' => 'stehr.reginald@schoen.org',
        'auth_key' => 'hk1pE_TUoUmqWcxoArOPmRb-t2P7LvKq',
        'password_hash' => '$2y$13$IsQxrCaLX4ficjulKKSEbucgLfTyyFSLle30efejBw1giKhwILGSm',
        'confirmed_at' => 1506074296,
        'flags' => 0,
        'created_at' => 1506074296,
        'updated_at' => 1506074296,
    ],
];
```

And token.php:

```
return [
    'token0' => [
        'user_id' => 1,
        'code' => 'nr3oU86ukLjb1oKIlKDBgnj0bWb96mNH',
        'created_at' => 1506074295,
        'type' => 1,
    ],
    'token1' => [
        'user_id' => 2,
        'code' => 'TTLcxuS_d_sYDME9m7VShbDsOMEVBqZq',
        'created_at' => 1506074295,
        'type' => 1,
    ],
];
```

Unfortunately the generated aliases will not be in sync with the record ID. Probably the yii2-faker extension should be changed to start at 1 to fix this.

Comment: Although this works, this is a hack. There should be some other solution where you can provide at least a random record from the related entity.
What if I want to generate 10 tokens and 2 users?